# How do I put this equation into python?

Tags: python

I need to put this equation

P*(1 + r/100n)^nt

into python. Can anyone help me?

I've tried this, but it won't get me right answer

```
p*(1+r/100*n)**(n*t)
```

p is 116000
 t is 35
 r is 4
 n is 12

I'm suppose to get $469,309.30 from above values, but the number I get is way too high. Its only been hours since I started to learn programming. I just have no idea what to do.

Comment: Try adding another parentheses to protect the multiplier to p. `p*((1+r/100*n)**(n*t))`. Order of precedence matters in such scenarios

Comment: You need a parens around ```100*n```.

Comment: Pemdas applies in Python too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> "${:,.2f}".format(p*(1+r/(100*n))**(n*t))

'$469,309.30'
```

**Explanation:**

```
PEMDAS - Rule
```

> Parentheses, Exponentiation, Multiplication, Division, Addition,
>   Subtraction

You need to follow this rule, while writing math equations in code.

In your case, `r` was divided by `100` as `/` comes first then it was multiplied by `n`.

Answer (score 5):

It might be an order of operations issue where Python is dividing `r` by 100 first. I would try the following:

```py
p*(1+r/(100*n))**(n*t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the PEMDAS rule and you'll be fine man :D.

```
p = 116000
t = 35
r = 4
n = 12

answer = p*(1+r/(100*n))**(n*t)
print(answer)

out: 469309.29562481085
```

Answer (score 1):

According to bodmas it will divide r by 100 so you need to use brackets at r/(100*n)

```
result=p*(1+r/(100*n))**(n*t)
print(result)

output:
469309.29562
```